# SQL Server Datacenter Backup compatibility

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, backup

I did a backup of my db on `SQL Server Datacenter Edition` and I need to Roll it up on `SQL Server Standard`. Is that possible? If so, what pitfalls are worth considering?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to look out for unsupported features which are present in Enterprise and not in Standard...

for Example,Partitioning is available in Enterprise,but not in Standard.so you will need to restore database and remove partitioning and then take a backup for it to work in Standard

Below DMV will provide list of Enterprise only features which will not work in standard..

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features
```

**References:**
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84456/downgrade-sql-server-enterprise-edition-to-sql-server-standard-edition
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sqlman/2011/03/25/sql-server-standard-vs-enterprise-edition/